# Criteria for being representation-infinite for subcategories of quiver algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a quiver algebra over a field $K$ (maybe we need algebraically closed?).
Then the following is two statements are well known:

1. In case $A$ is representation-infinite, every Auslander-Reiten component contains indecomposable modules of arbitrary large dimension.
2. In case there is an indecomposable modules of dimension larger than $\max(2 \dim(A),30)$, $A$ is representation-infinite.

Question:
Can those two statements be generalised from the category $\text{mod-}A$ to certain subcategories of $\text{mod-}A$ that have Auslander-Reiten sequences, maybe when replaying the bound $\max(2 \dim(A),30)$ by some other finite bound? I'm especially interested in the full subcategory of Gorenstein projective $A$-modules in case $A$ is Gorenstein or some other functiorially finite resolving subcategories.

Comment: An analogue of the first statement is contained in the PhD thesis of Matthias Krebs entitled "Auslander-Reiten theory in functorially finite resolving subcategories", Theorem 2.2.9 with no explicit bound.